# Can we export named and default helper in Ember

Tags: ember.js

```
/* 
 * highlight-text.js
 */
export function yellow(text) {
    return Ember.String.htmlSafe('<span class='yellow'>'+text+'</span>');
}

export function red(text) {
    return Ember.String.htmlSafe('<span class='red'>'+text+'</span>');
}

export yellow helper(yellow);
export default helper(red);
```

My template looks like this

```
{{red 'text'}} 
{{yellow 'text'}}
```

What is the correct way to do this?
Note: I don't want to pass class name as argument.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do in one file. Make two files with different names

Comment: You cannot do this from one file, the helper name that you will be accessing from the template will be `{{highlight-text }}` and not `{{red/yellow}}`, you could have your functions live under a `utils/` and then re-export the functions from helper files named accordingly.

Comment: Okay..I will try to implement using utils